# Rotated Datagrid Navigation Problems

Tags: wpf

I am working a program that uses Datagrids to display most of the data. In order to match the old version of the program it is necessary to rotate the built in Datagrid from WPF so that each item is a column versus a row.

Example: on the left is the behavior built into wpf and on the right is what we want to achieve.

[image]

So far, the only solution we've come across is to rotate the grid from the xaml. This works fine and gets the look we want but it causes several issues with usability. Other approaches to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRotatedStyle" TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridTabGrids}">
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                            <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    <TextBlock Height="100" Text="Binding Image" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
    <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="100"/>
</Style >

<Style x:Key="DataGridRotatedCellsBaseStyle" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
</Style >
```

If this is the only practical solution to the problem then we have yet to figure out a good solution to the bugs introduced by this approach.

First off, the arrow keys are all rearranged as they do not receive the same rotation treatment. I have seen solutions that capture the key stroke in the code behind and just change, say, Left Arrow to Up Arrow. But this seems like a pretty sub optimal way to go about it. I've also seen where you capture key down events and manually set the selected cell, but again, this seems unclean to me.

Second, the mouse wheel scrolling also suffers from the same lack of rotation in it's logic and is now scrolling horizontally. The suggested solutions for this are similar to the arrow keys. Another solution is to set up your own scroll viewer and then mess with rerouting the mouse wheel event from the datagrid to the new scroll viewer.

There are other problems with changed formatting of colors, alignment issues and the ability to automatically enter edit mode when the user starts typing.

So my overarching question is: Is this even the right way to go about this? And if so, are the solutions to these resulting problems going to be necessarily messy or is there a cleaner way to approach this whole thing?

Comment: I am having the same problems any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, as far as the keyboard arrows are concerned, so I share my solution here.

Just subscrive the `PreviewKeyDown` of the `DataGrid`, in my case

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single"PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"
```

and in code behind you can "fix" the correct key:

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Left)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg != null && (dg.CurrentItem != dg.Items[0]))
        {
            Send(Key.Up);
        }
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg != null && (dg.CurrentItem != dg.Items[dg.Items.Count - 1]))
        {
            Send(Key.Down);
        }
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg != null && (dg.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex + 1 < dg.Columns.Count))
        {
            Send(Key.Right);
        }
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg != null && (dg.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex - 1 >= 0))
        {
            Send(Key.Left);
        }
    }
}
```

where the `Send` is adapted [from this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9179a76e-250f-416e-9590-dd7d21ef29f5/simulating-keystrokes-in-cwpf?forum=wpf).

```
private void Send(Key key)
{
    if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice != null)
    {
        if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource != null)
        {
            var e1 = new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, key) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
            bool b = InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e1);
        }
    }
}
```

It can be useful also to manage the page up/down event:

```
if (e.Key == Key.PageDown)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dg != null)
    {
        if (dg.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dg, 0) as Decorator;
            if (border != null)
            {
                var scroll = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
                if (scroll != null) scroll.PageRight();
            }
        }
    }
}
if (e.Key == Key.PageUp)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dg != null)
    {
        if (dg.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dg, 0) as Decorator;
            if (border != null)
            {
                var scroll = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
                if (scroll != null) scroll.PageLeft();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, sometimes narrow minded people don't understand that freezing the first N columns of a standard grid is equivalent to freezing the first N rows of a rotated grid, for example just the first one:

```
<DataGrid FrozenColumnCount="1"
```

In the above case for the usability of the Home key:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Home)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dg != null)
    {
        dg.CurrentColumn = dg.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(1);
    }
}
```